# Allow certain tags in htmlpurifier

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

So I'm using htmlpurifier and I'm trying to allow the `map` and `area` tags. So I did this

```
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'map, area');
```

Now I load up the page and I get

> Warning: Element 'map' is not supported (for information on implementing this, see the support forums)

and

> Warning: Element 'area' is not supported (for information on implementing this, see the support forums

I checked out the forums, but couldn't really find anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define your attributes list in HTMLPURIFIER Library. By default it does not contain image map and area tages.

See this link below
http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,5046

In this link the code explains how to define your tags, which are not included in library and also set their required attributes.

I hope it will help.

Happy Coding!

Atul